# Is it possible to attach a point light to a single vertex?

Tags: modifiers, lighting

I have a scene where I'm deforming a model of a hallway with a Twist modifier. My goal is to attach point lights to the mesh so they will change their position when the twist is applied.

[image]

[image]

Is this possible? If not, is there a workaround to achieve what I'm going for without having to keyframe each point light individually? I want to render this in eevee, so going the route of an emissive material isn't ideal.

Comment: yes it works, select your light, shift select your mesh, switch to Edit mode, select one or 3 vertice and press Ctrl P in order to parent, but of course you need one or 3 vertices close to the light

Comment: Brings back memories of LoZ-OoT ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select your light, shift select your mesh, switch to *Edit* mode, select one or 3 vertice and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>P</kbd> in order to parent, but of course you need one or 3 vertices close to the light.